# Setting up DDNS server behind router and gateway

Tags: router, firewall, home-server

I set up a server using DDNS on my home network, and despite setting up port forwarding on the router it still doesn't work - attempts to connect just time out.

However, I can access the web page using that computer's local IP address from other machines on the local network, so I think there must still be some block externally.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I forgot to configure the Gateway as well as the Router...

Once I set up port forwarding from the gateway to the router, then from the router to my computer, it was fine.

Just in case anyone else has the same problem.